# Entity Framework not seeding data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm building a WPF application with EF Code First.

My database is created but when I try to seed data inside it on initialization, it fails (no data is inserted).

This is my initializer:

```
public class MyDBContextSeeder : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDBContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDBContext context)
    {
        IList<Dog> defaultDog = new List<Dog>();
        defaultDog.Add(new Dog("Spike"));

        foreach (Dog d in defaultDog)
            context.Dogs.Add(d);

        // more data here....

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

In another class I have `MyDBContext`

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext() : base("MyDB")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new MyDBContextSeeder());
    }
    //public DbSet<>.....
}
```

And then I've inserted this code in `App.xamls.cs`, overriding OnStartup method.

```
using (var db = new MyDBContext())
{
  Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDBContext>());
  new MyDBContextSeeder().InitializeDatabase(db); 
}
```

If I don't use `new MyDBContextSeeder().InitializeDatabase(db)` my database isn't created.

By the way, I really can't get why I don't have any data inside my database. 
Migrations are enabled. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you tried to change the model, or drop objects of your database to trigger the ContextSeeder? Remember that it will only `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi I'm a beginner..what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that EF will only call `MyDBContextSeeder.Seed()` method if Model (entities) changes. Try to drop some or all your table in you database context, or add a new property at your Dog class, and put a breakpoint at `MyDBContextSeeder.Seed()` method to follow up.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi I understand now what you mean, but it's not seeding any data even if I change to `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`

Comment: Aren't you missing a SaveChanges() at the end of Seed() method?

Comment: Yes, I'm missing it. At the end of Seed(), after `base.Seed(context);` ?

Comment: you got it! Add `context.SaveChanges()` there and enjoy!

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi I still don't have data in database..

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly inserting your dogs inside the `DbContext`, but you're not saving changes. Please, add a call to `context.SaveChanges()` at the end of the `.Seed()` method and your dogs should appear in the DB. Woof! Woof!

Comment: Where do I have to call it? Inside DbContext or DbContextSeeder?

Comment: I still don't have any data inside database

Comment: The `.Seed` method is run only if the database is initialized. The initialization happens when the database is created. You can force it by calling `context.Database.Initialize(false)`. Try doing it with this method, instead of the one you're using. The `context.SaveChanges()` is still neceasary. Force the initialization by manually dropping the db, or by changing the model definition (add temporarily a dummy column).

Comment: BTW, it's enough with setting the initializer in the DbContext constructor. You don't need to do it anywhere else. OTOH, if you don't force the DB initialization it happens the first time you instance and use the DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
public class MyDBContextSeeder : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDBContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MyDBContext context)
        {
            IList<Dog> defaultDog = new List<Dog>();
            defaultDog.Add(new Dog("Spike"));

            foreach (Dog d in defaultDog)
                context.Dogs.Add(d);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

--

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    static MyDBContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new MyDBContextSeeder());
    }
}
```

Comment: Still no data inside database